# Do I have to pay back an Australian IPRS Scholarship, if I decide to quit my PhD?

Tags: phd, funding, australia

I am currently in an application process for a PhD position in Australia and my advisors said that I might be eligible for an [IPRS](https://www.education.gov.au/international-postgraduate-research-scholarships) Scholarship.
Obviously this is a great opportunity, but at the same time also a major life changing decision to leave my home country for a three year PhD program abroad.
Before I make my final decision, I of course want to think of all possible risks involved.

**So here is my question:** Do you know if I have to pay back the funds recieved by the IPRS Scholarship or and University / Project money if I decide to quit my PhD?
Does anyone of you have any experiences regarding this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Ask that at IPRS, not here. It is a perfectly valid question, and it should not mean to them that you consider quitting, just that you are asking about every eventualities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say no.  When you are awarded an IPRS, you will get the conditions that you need to adhere to.  At my university, there is no clause that says you have to pay back anything if you quit.

If I were you, apply first, and if you are successful, look at the conditions carefully.